# Issue with Magento Tax setup India

Tags: tax

I am have question on setting up tax in Magento ver. 1.7.0.2, My requirement is I want to add the product price including tax and it should display same price in all the pages like product view, shopping cart and checkout page. but in invoice it should show the what is the price excluding tax and tax amount and total amount including tax. but with below settings it is not working.

Example in admin I have added 890 which is including 14.5% VAT however in product listing page it shows excluding price of Rs 777.29.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put the price including tax of the product under catalogue (Manage product, Add Product, Price) 890/- if you are choosing catalogue prices “Including tax” under Tax calculation configuration.

[image]

If you are putting the price under catalogue (Manage product, Add Product, Price) Excluding tax 777.29/- then choose the option catalogue prices “Excluding price” Under Tax Calculation configuration.